# How to terminate a process when other process finishes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have created three functions where on the first I have created a countdown timer and on the other two I find prime numbers. I am using `multiprocessing` to make them execute together. What I am trying to make it do is when the timer finishes the other two process will also terminate. The other two functions will keep searching for the prime numbers until the timer finishes e.g. if timer is set to 1 minute, the functions will keep searching for prime numbers for one minute.

Right now the code waits n seconds before checking for the next number. What I did is I passed from the countdown function to the other two the seconds when they reach 0 to terminate the loop inside the other two functions.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process

def countdown(t): 
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60) 
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs) 
        print(timer, end="\r") 
        time.sleep(1) 
        t -= 1

def isPrime1():
    f = open('results.txt','w')
    i = 2
    while countdown(t) != 0:
        c = 0;
        for j in range (1, (i + 1), 1):
            a = i % j
            if (a == 0):
                c = c + 1

        if c == 2:
            f.write(str(i))
            print(i)
            if countdown(t) == 0:
                break
        i = i + 1
    f.close()

def isPrime2():
    f = open('results1.txt','w')
    i = 2
    while countdown(t) != 0:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        c = 0;
        for j in range (1, (i + 1), 1):
            a = i % j
            if (a == 0):
                c = c + 1

        if c == 2:
            f.write(str(i))
            print(i)
            if countdown(t) == 0:
                break
        i = i + 1
    f.close()

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = int(input("Seconds:"))
    p1 = Process(target=isPrime1())
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=isPrime2())
    p2.start()
    p3 = Process(target=countdown(t))
    p3.start()
```

Comment: Your function countdown does not return anything, so the loop `while countdown(t) != 0:` will never end and condition `if countdown(t) == 0:` is always `false`

Comment: @Yuri Ginsburg: Actually `countdown(t) != 0` will always be **`True`** because the function implicitly returns `None` when it finishes.

Comment: @martineau You are right. My mistype. Anyway, this code never finishes.

Comment: GM173: Each process runs in its own memory-space, so there is a different "global" variable `t` in each one (none of which are the same as the one in the main thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event). They are a synchronization technique used for communication among processes, built on synchronization primitives like lock/mutex.

Each process has its own assigned memory region where variables are allocated, so variables are not shared among different processes. This is one of the main differences between processes and threads (threads share the same memory).
When you create (=fork) a process, the variables of the original (father) process are copied in the new process (child) memory region. So they will have the same value at the beginning, but changes done after the fork will not be seen by the other processes.

In your case, every process has its own copy of the `t` variable and it doesn't see the changes that the other processes make to their copy.

See this as an example program that does what you want using Events:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Event

def countdown(event, t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    # Set the event to notify the other processes
    event.set()
    print("Countdown done")

def isPrime(event):
    # This loop ends when the countdown is over
    while not event.is_set():
        # Your code here
        pass
    print("Done!")

if __name__=='__main__':

    t = int(input("Seconds:"))
    event = Event() # the event is unset when created
    p1 = Process(target=isPrime, args=(event,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=isPrime, args=(event,))
    p2.start()
    p3 = Process(target=countdown, args=(event,t,))
    p3.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
```

and this is the result:

[image: output]

P.S. You don't need to duplicate the code for the function. You can use the same function to run as many processes as you want. They will proceed independently.
You should also use `join` to make the original process wait for the end of its children.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Conditions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Condition), [Events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event), and other synchronization primitives.

PS: It will be better in any way than any kind of global variable (because processes do not share their state, and each process will have its own copy of state inherited from the parent process during fork).